# Physical path of service

Tags: 2013, web-services, sharepoint-on-prem, path

Does anyone know what the physical path is of the data services in SharePoint 2013?

For example for this one and/or where to find the code behind of that services?

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find it for the userprofiles, but since I just needed a DataService used in SharePoint, I found ListData.svc which is located at this path:

```
http://localhost/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Parts
```

And physical path:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\ListData.svc
```

The servicehost of the ListData.svc is (here you can also find the used factory and codebehind):

```
<%@ServiceHost language="C#" Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressDataServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Service="Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ListDataService, Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataService, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

For user Profile

- WebService Url : `http://<site URL>/_vti_bin/userprofileservice.asmx`
- Physical Path: `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\userprofileservice.asmx`

Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvcuserprofileservice.aspx

Also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515344.aspx